# Sequence Permission in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sequence

How can I check a permission granted for particular sequence and assign permission to particular sequence from SQL*Plus?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

To grant a permission:

```
grant select on schema_name.sequence_name to user_or_role_name;
```

To check which permissions have been granted

```
select * from all_tab_privs where TABLE_NAME = 'sequence_name'
```

Answer (score 7):

Just another bit. in some case i found no result on   **all_tab_privs**! i found it indeed on       **dba_tab_privs**. I think so that this last table is better to check for any grant available on an object (in case of impact analysis). The statement becomes:

```
    select * from dba_tab_privs where table_name = 'sequence_name';
```

Comment: Regular users usually don't have access to any of the `DBA_xxx` views.

Comment: Sure, you are right! But the fact is that i needed to evaluate impacts of a sequence renewal on an Oracle table. with credentials different from DBA ones I didn't find the grant set for other users. with sys credentials i found 3 dependent schemas I will miss if stopped to the first statement (with disservices in prod environment).

Comment: I forgot to say thanks for the answer of beny23. essential to look for and find DBA's view ;)